# var username= '<%=Session["username"]%>' for access session value in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I am making star rating code and try to store the rating along with which username.For this i used session to store username in session variable.Now,i am trying to access that session in javascript and using ajax try to store rating and username which i will get from session into db.but when i give rating.it store it on db but not get the username.i am making website and using php,html,javascript and ajax.My server is xammp.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow please consider posting what you have tried so far

Comment: A piece of code would be helpful. I suppose that there is a problem around your insert Statement.

Comment: I resolved my issue.